# The 'pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1' distribution was not found and is required by google-auth

Tags: python, conda, geemap

I wanted to try Python's `Geemap` module, I installed it via `conda install geemap -c conda-forge`. But when importing it in my pyhton code I have this error message :`The 'pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1' distribution was not found and is required by google-auth`. So I updated `pyasn1-modules`, and now I have version 0.2.8 but the errors remains.
If someone has a idea...

Comment: Something in current environment might be in conflict: try creating a new environment for it with `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge geemap`

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the version by conda and install the one by pip

```
conda remove --force pyasn1-modules
pip install pyasn1-modules
```

That solved the problem for me - although it doesn't make sense that it should!

Answer (score 0):

Conda was the problem for me. Tried creating a new environment and installing everything with pip and that got rid of the error.